# SVN - Change working copy to point at new svn path

Tags: svn, path, working-copy

I've got a SVN Repository that has moved to a new address/path. However, I've got a working copy with uncommitted source code still pointing to the old (now invalid) repository path. How do you change a working copy to point at a new repository?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

[`svn switch --relocate`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html) is deprecated as of version 1.7 of subversion. Use the [`svn relocate`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html) command instead.

It takes either `FROM-PREFIX TO-PREFIX [PATH...]` or `TO-URL` as arguments.

See

`svn help relocate`

for more information.

Answer (score 59):

Use the [`svn switch`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re27.html) command with the `--relocate` command line option.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I used:

svn switch --relocate file:///Users/user/old_repository/project/trunk file:///Users/user/new_repository/project/trunk

Comment: Does not fix the URLs in svn:externals. Any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 29):

Using [TortoiseSVN](http://www.TortoiseSVN.net)

1. Right click on working copy and select 'SVN Switch...'
2. On 'Switch to branch' form Select new SVN path

---

Using Command

1. Open console
2. Navigate to the working copy `cd [working copy path]`
3. Write the command `svn relocate [new url]`

Comment: This is applicable only if using TortoiseSVN, which the poster didn't indicate he or she is using.

Comment: Hi @zck please note that I wrote 2 solution in 1 answer first TortoiseSVN and **the second is Command this command is deprecated for subversion in general** you can review this page [svn relocate/svn Subcommands](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html)

Comment: Well, your answer was edited after I commented to include a commandline way of doing it. That commandline answer was already posted in June, so there's no need to repeat it.

Comment: No, I post the answer in its current words my edit just for improve formatting; and I think the command I wrote is more clear than the one was wrote in June

Comment: The TortoiseSVN GUI way requires a click  on 'relocate', and not switch.  Which makes sense given the command line..  Not sure what switch would do -- it seemed to be trying to access the old URL and the new URL, something I didn't want it to do.

Answer (score 12):

To be more precise

```
svn switch --relocate [complete url of the old repo] [complete url of the new repo]
```

For example:

```
svn switch --relocate  http://svn.repo.com:9880/website/branches  http://svnrepo.com/web/branches
```

Answer (score 4):

Using TortoiseSVN
[tortoisesvn docs](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html)

1. Go to the working copy's root folder
2. Right Click, Click TortoiseSVN Submenu, Click Relocate.
3. Enter the new path

Answer (score 1):

**Very Simple :**

**Step 1:** Open command prompt / terminal and set workpath

**Step 2:** Execute this line `svn switch --relocate http://newurl`

Answer (score 0):

I had changed my svn server to force redirect everything from HTTP to HTTPS (and it could have been a redirect to any other URL), and I noticed that this `svn relocate` command was causing lots of problems with externals. Fortunately I found that the easiest thing was to just do an `svn update` and due to the redirect of the svn server, it updated all the URLs store in the local working copy, including the externals.